# Parent transaction is getting affected while child transaction is marked as rolled back

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

In my application, I am trying to absorb a runtime exception in a catch block when trying to commit that transaction

But I am getting `RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`.

As per my knowledge, whenever a runtime exception is thrown that particular transaction will be marked as rolled back.

But in my code, I am catching the exception in a new transaction, then how parent transaction is getting affected?

Code:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
Class A{
    void method1() {
        b.method2();
    }
}

class B {
    void method2() {
        c.method3();
    }
}


class C {
    void method4() {
        method5();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    method5() {
        save();  \\ saving data in this line
        try {
            flush();
        } catch(Exception e ) {

        }
    }

}
```

In this code, an exception is thrown in method5() and that method is under a new transaction. Then how the parent transaction (in Class A) is getting affected?

If you can provide the solution that will be helpful

Comment: Hibernate doesn't support nested transaction rollback.

Comment: @talex Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: There is not much to elaborate. I't doesn't support it. The reason behind is it will be difficult to implement without some sort of STM (software transnational memory) because rollback of inner transaction requires roll back of state of all entities.

Comment: Ok. Could you please provide any alternative solution to skip that exception and proceed. I tried norollbackFor="OptimisticLockException.class" , but that is also not working.

Comment: I doubt that there is any solution and even there is any, then they will require HUGE AMOUNT OF BLACK MAGIC. Hibernate is not designed to support restore after failure. Theyr approach "fail and try from scratch". So you have to rethink your workflow.